# Added new Rails controller using "generate controller" but can't load page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a Rails app that has only consisted of backend code so far (a little custom workflow engine, Redis, foreman, etc).  Today I tried to add the first controller to the application, but I can't get the new controller to load.

I used:

```
rails generate controller CollectedData new --no-test-framework
```

And got back:

```
  create  app/controllers/collected_data_controller.rb
   route  get "collected_data/new"
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/collected_data
  create    app/views/collected_data/new.html.erb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/collected_data_helper.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/collected_data.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/collected_data.css.scss
```

And I also ran `rake routes` and got this:

```
collected_data_new GET /collected_data/new(.:format) collected_data#new
```

But whenever I load `http://localhost:3000/collected_data/new` in my browser, I get:

```
Not Found: /collected_data/new
```

Here is the content of my routes.rb file:

```
Crows::Application.routes.draw do
  get "collected_data/new"

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Procfile contents:

```
redis: redis-server config/redis/redis.conf
clock: bundle exec rake resque:scheduler --trace
cp_resp_poller: bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=cp_resp_poller
cp_req_sender: bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=cp_req_sender --trace
server: rails server
```

I have also tried restarting WEBrick.

Update: I noticed that Webrick is returning HTTP 404 when requesting this controller (or any new controller that I've tried to add, for that matter).

FIXED: Please see my own answer to this question.

Comment: Please tell us what is the error in your server console...

Comment: Nothing is being written to the console and nothing relevant is showing up in log/development.log.

Comment: Show your `routes.rb` file, I suspect a precedence issue w/o knowing anything more.

Comment: Added routes.rb content to original posting.

Comment: You mentioned foreman, what is inside your Procfile? is the Not Found error from the browser, from the webserver, or from rails?

Comment: Added Procfile contents to original posting.

Comment: The browser is displaying `Not Found: /collected_data/new` when I try to load `http://localhost:3000/collected_data/new`.

Comment: And you are starting the server through foreman correct?

Comment: treehau5: Correct. I have also tried this when starting the server manually (`rails server` from the command-line) and get the same results.

Comment: I think the problem at this point is, with all your backend work, it could be any number of things that are localized to your environment that we cant see, I could help you track it down but that would require taking a look at most of the config files.

Comment: FWIW, I noticed that I can run the controller through `rails console` and get the expected HTML response by executing `app.get '/collected_data/new'` and then `app.response`.

Comment: treemau5: Any help that you can offer would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you giving us the entire message displayed by the browser? Please post the development.log (clear it first and then make a single request)

Comment: @stevanity Yep, that's the entire message, cut and pasted. Along with a 404 status code if you look at the HTTP response headers. There was nothing showing up in the development log because Webrick wasn't really hooking into my Rails application for these requests.  See the end of the original post for an update I just made re: the fix I found.

Comment: @DanD.Thats cool. nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED: I fixed this by changing my config.ru file.

The original contents were:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Crows::Application

require 'resque/server'
run Rack::URLMap.new "/resque" => Resque::Server.new
```

I fixed the controller not found issue by commenting out the last two lines above related to Resque. Those last two lines were added early on while developing the workflow/backend part of my application and enable a web-based admin interface for Resque.

Update: I now have my Rails app (plus its web controllers, etc) and the Resque web admin interface running side-by-side. I got this working by removing those last two lines from the config.ru file and adding the following lines to my routes.rb file:

```
resources :resque_web_admin
mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"
```